# How can I personalize my textView?

Tags: android, text, textview

Yesterday I asked a question about the TextView. I read and I see that it's very difficult to understand. So, I'm sorry.
Now I explain better my problem:
I try to personalize my TextView. I tried two different things:

1. I use photoshop, I made an image text and I use it as a drawable. The image re-sized isn't with right quality
2. I try to use the text of TextView, but I can't change the family of the text (the app crashed). Then I don't know how to set gradient as text color and border in the text.

What can I do?

Edit: yes! For the point 1 I use an ImageView inside of TextView. In point 2 I use TextView. I have problem in both situation!

Comment: can you give some link for image so that we can help you?

Comment: if you want to use image then use imageView not textView

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira You can use images in TextViews. As backgrounds and/or as **compound drawables**.

Comment: You asked a bunch of questions in one...

Answer (score 0):

I think to customize textview (any view) you have to implement your own custom view by creating your custom class.
Here is link for custom text view,i hope i will find it useful
http://www.jayway.com/2012/06/25/creating-custom-android-views-part-1-extending-standard-views-and-adding-new-xml-attributes/